# SELECT column_name FROM (SELECT table_name FROM TABLE_OF_TABLES)

Tags: mysql, subquery, union

I have a table of tables called TABLES.  TABLES has a column TABLE_NAME.

For each TABLE_NAME there exists a table in the database.  All of these tables are structured the same.

Ultimately I would like to UNION columns from each of these tables. But I'm not getting close to that objective.

I am stuck on the following query:

```
SELECT column_name FROM (SELECT table_name FROM TABLES) T;
```

The error returned is `"ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'column_name' in 'filed list'.`

I haven't seen a good representation of `SELECT...FROM (SELECT...FROM)`

Any help is most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to achieve this with a static query. If you really need this for some reason you have to use dynamic SQL

```sql
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('SELECT column_name FROM `', table_name, '`') SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL ')
  INTO @sql
  FROM tables;

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f6440/4)** demo

To simplify things on the calling side you can always wrap it in a stored procedure.

Comment: So I'm wondering if I am too far off the 'good structure' path.  I have many tables, need to UNION for several functions...should I just have ONE BIG TABLE?

Comment: You're quite welcome. Answering to your question, the fact that you find yourself in a situation when you need to use dynamic sql for simple/ordinary things is almost always is an indication that your db schema has some room for improvement.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
SELECT column_name FROM (SELECT column_name FROM TABLES) T;
```

OR

```
SELECT column_name FROM (SELECT * FROM TABLES) T;
```